# jQuery Datepicker not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use jQuery datepicker tool but it's not working. I am new to jQuery so I don't know much about it. Can someone spot where I have gone wrong? Are my links in the header correct?

html:

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>CodeProject</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body><h2>Date Picker</h2>
        <p>I will be making a simple date picker tool using jQuery. You have have seen it in some</br> travel websites where when you move your cursor on a date field, you see a little pop-up which allows you to pick a date.</p></br>
        <p>Departure date:<input type="text" id="departure"></p>
        <p>Returning date:<input type="text" id="returning"></p>
        <button>Submit</button>
</body>
```

jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#departure").datepicker();
$("#returning").datepicker();
});
```

CSS file:

```
    #header {
    background-color: white; /**#212121**/
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: 1px;
    width: 99.2%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;

}

h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    color: #444;
    padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    font-size: 51px;
    line-height: 44px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

span {
    color: #7EAEDE;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;

}

h2 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #222;
}

h4 {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666666;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left!important;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

#p1 {
    font-family:  'Hoefler Text', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1BA8E0;
}

body {
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0; /**body has margin by default so we 0 to get rid of it **/
}

#wrapper {
    width:700px; /**Get everything in the wrapper to be within this width of 700px**/
    margin: 0 auto; /**centre everything**/
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.border { /**Separated by a dotted line**/
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;    
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Comment: it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/qcdUE/

Comment: Really stupid question... you do have <script> tags around your JS right?  This looks ok to me...

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: make sure you include the css file too

Comment: Change your script source to have a `http://`

Comment: I think Ohgodwhy's answer is the good one.
Adam, protocol is not mandatory, starting url with `//` is ok.

Comment: @AdamPlocher would I still need <script> tags when my js is in a seperate file?

Comment: @user123 nope, sorry, I didn't realize that until after my comment :)

Comment: @MikeC. I have now added the CSS file

Comment: No, i mean the jquery-ui.css file needs included on your page. The datepicker won't work without it.

Comment: @MikeC. oh, I don't have that file. Can you tell me how does that work by posting it as an answer, please? I am new to this jQuery business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the info you requested, note the order, this is taken directly from the [JQuery API page](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for the datepicker, so you should follow it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

What I've found is JQuery plugins tend not to work if you forget to include their .css file. Since you were already referencing the online version of the file, I just included that reference for you. If this continues to not work for you, make sure you have no issues with accessing these file by browsing to these links directly.

If it continues to fail, watch your console while loading the page and check for any errors. This is always a good place to start figuring things out.

Comment: Thanks a lot mike. It's working now :). So i have to refer to the  JQuery API page everytime when I want to insert a new jquery tool? or will this jquery-ui.css link reference would work for every other tool?

Comment: That will work with all of the jquery-ui tools http://api.jqueryui.com/category/widgets/ If you download a custom jquery plugin, they usually have their own .css file.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the JS file you want to perform actions from

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript.js'></script>
```

Before you ever invoke jQuery and the jQueryUI components.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Change your order of operation here and put `javascript.js` after those two files.

Comment: That didn't work either. Btw I am using sublime text 2 editor. It's not done differently to any other editor is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this you missed `http:` here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Markup:

```
<html>
        <head>  
            <title>CodeProject</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
            <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body><h2>Date Picker</h2>
            <p>I will be making a simple date picker tool using jQuery. You have have seen it in some</br> travel websites where when you move your cursor on a date field, you see a little pop-up which allows you to pick a date.</p></br>
            <p>Departure date:<input type="text" id="departure"></p>
            <p>Returning date:<input type="text" id="returning"></p>
            <button>Submit</button>
    </body>
```